# What's wrong with this Excel VBA Command Macro?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to get my whole workbook to recalculate.

Sometimes it'll give me

> Ambiguous Name Errors RE: Workbook_RefreshAll()

and sometimes other stuff.

What am I doing wrong? Office 365 - Excel.

```
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 0
Public Const cRunWhat = "Workbook_RefreshAll()"

Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, cRunIntervalSeconds, 1)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, _
         Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, _
       Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=False
End Sub

Sub Workbook_RefreshAll()
    Application.CalculateFullRebuild
    ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
    Call StartTimer
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you post your spreadsheet to Onedrive / Google Docs / Dropbox, etc, so we can take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 0
Public Const cRunWhat as String = "Refresh"

Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, cRunIntervalSeconds, 1)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=False       
End Sub 

Sub Refresh()    
   Application.CalculateFullRebuild
   ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
   StartTimer    
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked once, then I got another Ambiguous error regarding "Refresh", then syntax error on Application.CalculateFullRebuild

Comment: I have completely removed Workbook_RefreshAll(). Do you have all the code stored in one module (not a sheet object)?

Comment: All code is stored in its own Module. Module2 for this one, as Module1 is already being used. It just gives me Ambiguous errors on Refresh constantly.

Comment: Try renaming it to for example RefreshData, on my PC I ran it without any errors.

Comment: I had two of the same modules, strictly because I wanted one with the cRunIntervalSeconds at 1 and another at 0. How can I switch between? I want one that's tamed at a refresh interval of 1 second and another that's constant like rapid fire, haha! Thanks though. You were right, it was my fault!

Comment: If you want to change the values, it's best not to declare `cRunIntervalSeconds` as constant, but read its value from cell, for example in cell A2 will be the interval value, and you just read it like RunIntervalSeconds = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a2").value

Comment: How would I do that?

Comment: The Sheet is Sheet6. U29 can have value of 1 and V29 can have value of 0. What would the code be edited to make this work? Sorry. I'd probably figure it out if I hadn't have stayed up for more than a day working on this stuff!

Comment: I supposed it would be better to place the interval in some visible place in the worksheet and treat cell's value as a setting, meaning one cell which can have various values set by user.

Comment: I can't figure it out, I'm afraid. Yes, I understand. But what do I replace in the code to have it read from Sheet6, V29?